# Celebrating the 7000th Question

Tags: discussion

Should there be a celebration on Mi Yodeya for the 7,000th question?
This would certainly be an apt opportunity to mark the growth of this great project.

Comment: For those unaware, the page http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions indicates, on the right side, how many questions there are.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15882/birkat-kohanim-at-a-late-musaf#comment32399_15887

Comment: @DoubleAA How could you tell it was the 10,000th answer? My link for it is http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15887/1569, which implies it's the 15,887th (unless 5,887 were deleted)

Comment: @ba You know, I don't remember. But you should know that in links, SE doesn't count answers and questions separately. For instance, see this variation on your link: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15887/1569. Perhaps at the time I noted that we had 5887 questions and subtracted.

Comment: @DoubleAA Actually, now that I think about it, you could have multiplied the number of questions by the [answer ratio](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/jewish-life-and-learning).

Comment: @ba I don't know if that would have been accurate enough

Comment: @DoubleAA Probably the stats card that is on beta sites, cf. http://anime.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @HodofHod Good call! That was pre-graduation.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if the best way to vote would be to post an answer, to comment on the question, or to just upvote the question, but I want to voice my strong support for this idea!!

Answer (score 1):

I have been accused of being many things. One of the top names is "wet blanket" and this isn't just because of my crying jags or frequent enuresis. I don't look to round numbers as a cause for celebration. Each question is a valuable addition (does the number 7000 includes closed questions) and we shouldn't be looking to make one arbitrary number anything more interesting. Our fascination with number ending in 5, or 0 or anything else is more a psychological crutch than anything imbued with real meaning. The survival of this site and its well being should be measured in time, hits or mentions on other sites. Otherwise, we run the risk of encouraging poor questions to reach a supposed milestone.

I'll shut up now...

Comment: +1 and yes, sir, I'll step away from your pristine lawn. Seriously, if you have any concrete ideas for milestones we ought to strive for and celebrate, please voice them!

Comment: now that you mention it, can't we take some of the most "interesting" questions which were given innovative or thorough treatments in answers and make them available as a print collection through a self publishing website like Lulu? Celebrate intellectual success with intellectual goods.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: But, but, isn't Moshiach supposed to come when we reach the 7000th question?